# How would I increment an alpha field in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I would like to increment an alpha field in a table.

```
a000001
a000002
a000003
a000004
```

etc.

Comment: Do you mean increment the same cell over time or have a list of cells that increment?

Comment: This is not possible on Word as far as I know... or was it a mistake to include the tag for Word?

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about filling a column with sequential values, and the values start in, say, A2:

```
="a"&TEXT(ROW()-1,"000000")
```

Copy that down the column as needed.  If it starts in a different row, adjust the subtraction so the first value is 1.

[image]

Comment: Simple drag down works. Just one question - if I use your formula, the result has one zero less than what i specified in the formula

Comment: @Prasanna: can you clarify?  I get the correct result.

Comment: This is what I'm referring to. http://i.imgur.com/xuWhnpw.png?1. Further I observed that since `ROW()` returns the current row number, I was unable to use the formula when the sequence started from row no.10. It gave incorrect results (as we expect)

Comment: @Prasanna: Your image shows that your format spec somehow changed in the last row (it's short by a zero, which is why the result lacks a zero). Also, the prior rows use a different formula because the string matches the row number instead of row()-1.  See my image http://imgur.com/EHSoTvH -- no problem at rows 10+.  Could your Excel need more coffee?

Answer (score 3):

Excel is pretty smart about this type of thing.

1. Type `a000001` in A1 and `a000002` in A2.
2. Select both cells.
3. Hover the cursor over the lower right corner until it turns into a black cross.

4a. Click and drag down.  Excel will automatically increment your counter as it fills down.

4b.  If you do this in a column that is adjacent to a column that already has values extending far down the page (many rows) you can double click on that lower right corner, and excel will fill down (with incrementation) as far as the adjacent column is filled in.

Answer (score 3):

If you can handle the fact that the cell content is NUMBERS, then entering them as in

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and then applying a custom "cell format" is yet another way to **see** the same in the cells.

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd>
Click "Custom" (user specified) in the left side list (last one)
Then type `a000000` in the format code/specifier field, then click OK.
Copy and fill as you would with any number.

*Works exactly the same in LibreOffice, only "names" differ*

Comment: Excellent observation on the word tag in the question. +1 for that. My question is if we do as per your approach and copy and paste the excel as  values then only the values without the `a0000` get copied... So the user needs to be careful

Comment: As you copy cells (including "fill down" i.e. drag to fill) you need to have at least two, if not three cells "pre-formatted" in the same style (I do not have Excel available, works with two in LibreOffice). I believe it should work then. Remeber the Custom formatting is just for display, this is "normal numbers" in other regards.